# Jquery how to call function with ca

Tags: jquery, html

Ey, I have a total value ouput and I wanted to add a function that's linked to it. But I'm having issues putting it together. I just get NaN or the "not defined" error in the console.

The function I want to use for the total value output:

```
  function updateyett(yett) {
    $amount = $('#yett'); // cache for later use
    if($('#CalculatorPlacing').is(':checked')) {
       $amount.val(parseInt($amount.val(),10) + yett);
    } else {
      $amount.val(parseInt($amount.val(),10) - yett);
    }
  }
```

My total value Jquery:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var begin = 720;
    $("#yett").val('Total €' + begin.toFixed(2));
    $("#FenceCorners").on("change", function() {
      var prev = $("#yett").val();
      prev = prev.split('€')[1];
      var updateyett1 = updateyett() // HERE I TRY TO LINK IT

      var total = ($(this).find(":selected").data("price") * 100) / 100;
      total = parseInt(begin) + parseInt(total) + parseInt(updateyett1); //use begin
      $("#yett").val('Total €' + total.toFixed(2));
    });
  });
```

My Total value HTML

```
<div class="SummaryRow">
  <h1><input type="yeets" name="_mdjm_event_cost" id="yett" class="mdjm-input-currency required" readonly="readonly" value="" placeholder="Totaal €0.00" style="
        height: 100px;
        width: 275px;
        margin-top: -40px;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;" />
  </h1>
</div>
```

As you can see I have tried some things in the Jquery, but havent really found a way to make it work, hope someone can put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial value of the input is an empty string. `parseInt("", 10)` returns `NaN` because there's no number there to parse.

Either initialize it as `value="0"` so it's always a number, or check for that in your code.

```
  function updateyett(yett) {
    $amount = $('#yett'); // cache for later use
    var oldamount = parseInt($amount.val(), 10);
    if (isNan(oldamount)) {
        oldamount = 0;
    }

    if($('#CalculatorPlacing').is(':checked')) {
        $amount.val(oldamount + yett);
    } else {
        $amount.val(oldamount - yett);
    }
  }
```